# Kotlin: String contains one of particular symbols

Tags: kotlin

I need to check if my string contains one (or more) symbols from set (assuming that ".", "$", "!"). How to check it without iteration of each symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myString.indexOfAny(charArrayOf('.', '$', '!')) >= 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Will print true if `string` contains any of the following ('.', '$', '!)

```
val illegalCharacters = setOf('.', '$', '!')
print(string.any(illegalCharacters::contains))
```

Comment: @ShadeToD what did you try? make sure to replace `string` with the String you want to test

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple method to do this in kotlin

```
val stringVal = "Hello, World!"
val containsSymbol = stringVal.findAnyOf(strings = listOf(".", "$", "!"), startIndex = 0, ignoreCase = false) != null
```

It can be made into an extension function if you like

```
fun String.containsSymbol(symbols: List<String>, startIndex: Int = 0, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): Boolean {
   return this.findAnyOf(symbols, 0, false) != null
}
```

Can be invoked like this `"Hello world".containsSymbol(listOf(".", "$", "!"))`